# CUDA 8.0 - cudaMemcpy() - linear or constant time operation?

Tags: cuda

Does CUDA 8.0 `cudaMemcpy()` copy over an entire block of memory at the same time, or byte by byte?

I want to limit copy time but I can't find anything in the docs specifying if `cudaMemcpy()` is a linear or constant time operation.

Comment: The more data you transfer, the longer the transfer will take, generally speaking.  You will certainly find small deviations from *perfectly linear* behavior, but at a high level the transfer has a particular speed in bytes/sec associated with it, and this speed is roughly constant for larger transfers.  You can get a sense of this using one of the CUDA profilers, or just by timing a particular transfer using various timing methods.  For small transfers, the transfer has a characteristic that is roughly a fixed time ("latency") plus a linear component.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to read more into the transfer process

Comment: Shortened the title and enhanced the formatting to make it more reader-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous memory transfers are not constant time, but rather have both a fixed latency component and a component which is proportional to the transfer size. At small sizes, latency dominates, at large sizes, the limiting transfer speed is limited by memory or bus bandwidth.

Consider the following trivial benchmark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

__global__ void memsetkernel(int *x, int n)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for(; tid < n; tid += stride) {
        x[tid] = threadIdx.x;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // size
    int n = 100;
    int nreps = 10;

    if (argc > 1) {
       n = std::stoi(std::string(argv[1]));
    }

    size_t sz = sizeof(int) * size_t(n);

    // host array
    int* host = new int[n];

    // allocate size ints on device
    int* device;
    cudaMalloc(&device, sz);
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    {
        int nthreads = 1024;
        int nblocks = std::max(1, std::min(13*2, n / nthreads));
        memsetkernel<<<nblocks, nthreads>>>(device, n);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaEventRecord(start);
        for(int i=0; i<nreps; i++) {
            memsetkernel<<<nblocks, nthreads>>>(device, n);
        }
        cudaEventRecord(stop);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        float milliseconds, kilobytes, bandwidth;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
        milliseconds /= float(nreps); // Average of nreps
        kilobytes = float(sz) / 1e3f;
        bandwidth = kilobytes / milliseconds;        
        std::cout << "kernel assignment: " << bandwidth << " Mb/s" << std::endl; 
    }

    {
        cudaMemcpy(host, device, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaEventRecord(start);
        for(int i=0; i<nreps; i++) {
            cudaMemcpy(host, device, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        }
        cudaEventRecord(stop);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        float milliseconds, kilobytes, bandwidth;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
        milliseconds /= float(nreps); // Average of nreps
        kilobytes = float(sz) / 1e3f;
        bandwidth = kilobytes / milliseconds;        
        std::cout << "DTOH: " << bandwidth << " Mb/s" << std::endl; 
    }

    {
        cudaMemcpy(device, host, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaEventRecord(start);
        for(int i=0; i<nreps; i++) {
            cudaMemcpy(device, host, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        }
        cudaEventRecord(stop);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        float milliseconds, kilobytes, bandwidth;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
        milliseconds /= float(nreps); // Average of nreps
        kilobytes = float(sz) / 1e3f;
        bandwidth = kilobytes / milliseconds;
        std::cout << "HTOD: " << bandwidth << " Mb/s" << std::endl; 
    }

    // reset device
    cudaDeviceReset();

}
```

Running this at different data sizes shows the following behaviour:

[image]

Both device-to-host and host-to-device asymptotically approach a value around 60% of the bandwidth of the PCI-e bus of the machine in question (about 6.5 Gb/s, higher can be reached using pinned host memory), while the kernel reaches about 70% of the main memory bandwidth of the GPU (150 Gb/s with a theoretical maximum bandwidth of about 224Gb/s).

NVIDIA ships a sample for measuring transfer bandwidth which you can read about [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#bandwidth-test). You could use this to explore the performance of your hardware for yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason I thought it possible to copy over an entire block of memory at the same time and transfer it given it was within the bandwidth. It should have occurred to me the transfer of the data is inevitably going to break it up into smaller chunks.

Comment: Note that [bandwidth](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)) has a unit of (giga/mega/kilo)bytes per second, and has little to do with the width of the communication channel (most likely [16 lanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) in the case of a GPU). Instead the name relates to the [spectral width of the frequency band](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(signal_processing)) used to transfer information.